# Find element by Node ID

Tags: forms, reactjs, react-native

I'm in the middle of building a react-native app and running into problems trying to find an element by it's Node ID.

Some context:

I'm using a Form library for my register form that has a handleFormFocus function. This gets triggered anytime any one of the inputs are focused. The parameters provided to that function are the event and the component ID (integer number), neither of which give me any useful information about which input was actually focused (i.e. "email"), but instead leave me with only an ID.

When I was using react-native 0.34 I was able to do the following:

`const ReactNativeComponentTree = require('react/lib/ReactNativeComponentTree');
    let targetComponent = ReactNativeComponentTree.getInstanceFromNode(component);
    let inputRef = targetComponent._currentElement.props.fieldRef;`

but since updating to 0.41 this no longer works. I get the following error:
`Unable to resolve module react/lib/ReactNativeComponentTree`

Anyone know how to accomplish finding an element by its id with react native 0.41?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Using an id for elements in react native is considered an anti-pattern. Why not just pass a ref?

Comment: @PaulBGD you're right. I had unusual problems with the ref because I'm using a form library that made it unclear how to access the isFocused property of the input field due to how the library wrapped a TextInput component. Anyway, your response galvanised me to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulBGD: It would be great if you could point us to the documentation warning this is an anti-pattern. It's also extremely difficult to find in the documentation how to achieve the same goal in an approved way. Especially for generated components as when mapping an array to a List.

Answer (score 0):

React 0.41+:

```
import ReactNativeComponentTree from 'react-native/Libraries/Renderer/src/renderers/native/ReactNativeComponentTree';
```

React 0.51+:

```
import ReactNativeComponentTree from 'react-native/Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeComponentTree';
```

Comment: Since the update to react 16.4 on the react-native repo (see here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/c749d951ada829c6f6fb76f35e68142e61054433) it appears that this module is no longer exposed, the file was delete in this commit : https://github.com/facebook/react/commit/e7bd3d59a :/